# firebase realtime database setting error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I can not load my data in firebase realtime database from my computer today. Whereas before this happened everything went well, I tried to open my firebase on another computer and everything went well. Why is this firebase realtime database error only on my computer, please help me to solve this problem.

This is the error that shows up when I open my firebase realtime database from my computer:

[image: My Problem]

Comment: I think you have to contact firebase support for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because console errors should be reported to Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/